# Issue when indexing to elasticsearch from apache nutch

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I was trying to index from apache nutch to single node ES cluster and got this error.

> org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to
>   deserialize exception response from stream Caused by:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to
>   deserialize exception response from stream    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:173)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unsupported version: 1  at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:46)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:301)     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:38)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:170)
>     ... 23 more

From further research I came to know I should have same jvm version on client and ES server. Reference : http://jontai.me/blog/2013/06/elasticsearch-remotetransportexception-failed-to-deserialize-exception-response-from-stream/

I'm using ES version **2.3.2** and my JVM version is **"1.8.0_91"**.
When I checked /plugins/indexer-elastic/plugin.xml,the version specified is **1.4.1**. I would like to know this could be the issue and a possible solution other than to downgrade ES cluster version. I would like to continue with ES 2.3.2. Please help me on this.

PS : The command I've used for indexing is **`bin/nutch index crawl/crawldb/ -linkdb crawl/linkdb/ crawl/segments/20160801174223/`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From further research I got the solution. The error is coming up because of the version mismatch in indexer plugin of nutch (which was ES 1.4.1).

One solution to this is to download the source from **https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/** and then customize the plugin version with your elastic server version by following these instructions given in ***src/plugin/indexer-elastic/howto_upgrade_es.txt***.

> 1. Upgrade elasticsearch dependency in src/plugin/indexer-elastic/ivy.xml
> 2. Upgrade the Elasticsearch specific dependencies in src/plugin/indexer-elastic/plugin.xml    To get the list of
>      dependencies and their versions execute:    $ ant -f ./build-ivy.xml
>      $ ls lib/
> 3. Build from nutch source folder using ant or any other build tool.

Then we can index to ElasticSearch without this issue. 
Cheers :)